# SAS import excel determinated variables

Tags: import, sas

I want to import a certain variables of an excel more than 40.
Would it be possible to import only the variables that I want in a step data with infile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use infile (without a *lot* of extra work, anyway) to read an excel file.

You can, however, embed `keep` statements in your proc import!

```
proc import file="path\to\myfile.xlsx" 
            out =mylib.mydata(keep=myvar)
            dbms=excel replace;
run;
```

Of course, libname access allows the same keep statements.

Comment: Yes, but i need import a csv with delimiter "|", its impossible to select a certain variables with infile in input? i try: first save in macro variables the variables that i want import(i save the position colum where stay variables that i want), and:data work.import_fb;
 infile "C:\Users\xe53650\Desktop\FB_201601.csv"
 delimiter = '|' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2;

    input 
     @&var_1 cod_dt
     @&var_2 cod_zona
     @&var_3 cod_cbc

Comment: Unless you have a huge number of fields (columns), I'd read them all and then discard them with a table parameter like `data mytable(keep=V1 V2 V6);`

Comment: If this is a pipe delimited file, then your question needs dramatic modification.